# Inverse image of a Borel set is a Borel set under measurable function

Tags: measure-theory

If I define a measurable function $f:E \to \Bbb R \cup \pm\{\infty\}$ where $E \subset \Bbb R^d$ is a measurable set as if $\forall a \in \Bbb R$, the set

$$f^{-1}([-\infty,a))=\{x \in E :f(x) < a\}$$ is measurable. Under this assumption is it true that inverse image of a borel set under a measurable function is borel set ? I think not we can only say it is measurable.

Comment: You should have $f: E \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \cup \{ \pm \infty \}$ since you take the inverse image of an interval that is contained only in the extended reals. Or, you can leave the codomain of $f$ alone, and rewrite your statement as $$f^{-1}( (-\infty,a)) = \{x \in E : f(x) < a \}$$

Comment: @mlg4080: sorry I forgot to mention about extended real number system.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the topology of $E$. Here is a simple example showing $f$ might not be Borel.

By definition, a function is Borel-measurable if the preimage of every open set is Borel. However, it can be shown that it suffices to show the the preimage of every half ray $[-\infty, a )$ is Borel.

Now the exampple. Set $E = \{0,1,2\}$ where the probability (measure) of each point is $1/3$. Now let $f(x)=x$. It is measurable since every subset of $E$ is measurable (this applies also to your definition).

Equip $E$ with the indiscrete topology. That is, $E$ and $\emptyset$ are the only open sets. This implies that the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is $\{\emptyset,E\}$.

Consider $f^{-1}([-\infty,2))=\{0,1\}$. It is the inverse image of a open set but $\{0,1\}$ is not a borel set of $E$. Hence $f$ is not a Borel-measurable function.

Lebesgue gave a characterization of all Borel functions in terms of pointwise convergence and continuity. But it requires a basic knowledge of the [Borel hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_hierarchy). Roughly speaking, functions that can be obtained :
(1) initially, as the pointwise limit of continous functions (call this class 1) and 
(2) as the pointwise limit of functions of the previous class (there are called Baire classes).
have a tight relationship to each level of the Borel hierarchy. Their preimages lie at each level.

If you are interested in these topic, look at A. Kechris's book *Classical Descriptive Set Theory*, which is the traditional discipline where Borel sets are studied in depth.

Comment: Forgive the newbie question here, but with the $E$ you've set up, and the indiscrete topology, would that induce a particular measure?

Comment: Also, it is legal to form the expression $f^{-1}([-\infty,2))$, when the range of $f$ is $E$?

Comment: @AdrianKeister (1) The topology of a set and a measure on it are independent concepts. You can change the topology without changing a measure. There is no obvious "induced measure" in this case although we have the following. Open sets generate a $\sigma$-algebra known as the Borel sets; for the indiscrete topology, the $\sigma$-algebra is just $\{\emptyset,E\}$ and one obtains a measure $\mu(\emptyset)=0$ and $\mu(E)=1$. Other subsets won't be measurable.

Comment: (2) The expression is legal since $f$ has counterdomain $\mathbb{R}$ (or the extended system). To define a function, its range must not necessarily equal its counterdomain.

Comment: Wonderful! Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If we have a measurable function $f: E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ all we know is that $\forall V \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $V$ is open, then $f^{-1}(V)$ is a measurable set. We do not know if $f^{-1}(V)$ is Borel even in the case that $V$ is open.

A function where the inverse image of an open set is Borel, instead of just measurable, is called a Borel mapping, Borel function, or Borel measurable function. Continuous functions, lower semi-continuous, and upper semi-continuous functions are examples of Borel functions.

[Here is more information](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Borel_function) on Borel functions.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that this is what you want, it depends on your definition of a measurable function. I assume that you mean that a function is measurable iff the inverse image of every set $([\infty,a)$ is lebesgue measurable. This is equivalent to requiring that the inverse image of every borel set is lebesgue measurable (since the intervals $[-\infty,a)$ generate the borel sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R\cup \{±\infty\}}$.

Here is an counterexample showing that if a function is lebesgue measurable, then the inverse image of every borel set is not always a borel set. A neater way to formulate this is: The class of lebesgue measurable functions is not a subset of the class of borel measurable functions. (The converse is obviously true).

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\cup \{±\infty\}$. Set $f(0,y)=1$ for all $y$ belonging to V, where V is the vitaliset. Set $f(x,y)=0$ otherwise.

- $f$ is lebesgue measurable (I leave it to you to check that. Hint: All you have to know is that the lebesgue algebra is complete).
- Further, $f^{-1}(1)=\{0\}\times V$, but this set is clearly not borel measurable as that would imply that $V$ is borel measurable. (This follows by the fact that the $x$-section of every borel set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is measurable in $\mathbb{R}$)